# Python group two lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have two lists:

```
             A = ['T', 'D', 'Q', 'D', 'D']
             sessionid = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Is there anyway i could group items in A for the same sessionid, so that i could print out the following:

```
              1: ["T", "D","Q"]
              2: ["D","D"]
```

Comment: did you hear about `itertools.groupby`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The itertools [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function is designed to do this sort of thing. Some of the other answers here create a dictionary, which is very sensible, but if you don't actually want a `dict` then you can do this:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

A = ['T', 'D', 'Q', 'D', 'D']
sessionid = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2]    

for k, g in groupby(zip(sessionid, A), itemgetter(0)):
    print('{}: {}'.format(k, list(list(zip(*g))[1])))
```

**output**

```
1: ['T', 'D', 'Q']
2: ['D', 'D']
```

[`operator.itemgetter(0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) returns a callable that fetches the item at index 0 of whatever object you pass it; `groupby` uses this as the key function to determine what items can be grouped together.

Note that this and similar solutions assume that the `sessionid` indices are sorted. If they aren't then you need to sort the list of tuples returned by `zip(sessionid, A)` with the same key function before passing them to `groupby`.

---

**edited** to work correctly on Python 2 and Python 3

Comment: thx for the code as i really dont want dict.  just testing ur code and it says "'zip' object is not subscriptable", any chance you know what happens?    i am using Python 3 on jupyter notebook

Comment: actually it prints out the results in parenthesis  ("T", "D"), any chance i could print out the results in brackets (e.g: ["T","D"]      ) ?  thx!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Not using `itertools`, you can use a dictionary:

```
index = 0
dict = {}
for i in sessionid:
    if not (i in dict):
        dict[i] = []
    else:
        dict[i].append(A[index])
    index += 1

print(dict) # {1: ['T', 'D', 'Q'], 2: ['D', 'D']}
```

And based on the remarks below:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dict = defaultdict(list)
for i, item in enumerate(sessionid):
    dict[item].append(A[i])
```

Comment: You could use `collections.defaultdict` to avoid the conditional check.

Comment: You could use enumerate to avoid incrementing the index yourself.

Comment: This overrides a keyword and includes unnecessary checks. A defaultdict avoids this.

Comment: Ugh! `enumerate` isn't necessary at all. Use zip. See Farhan's solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a dictionary and `zip`:

```
A = ['T', 'D', 'Q', 'D', 'D']
sessionid = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2]

result = {i:[] for i in sessionid}
for i,j in zip(sessionid,A):
    result[i].append(j)
```

Or you can use `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in zip(sessionid, A):
   result[k].append(v)
```

Output:

```
>>> result
{1: ['T', 'D', 'Q'], 2: ['D', 'D']}
```

Answer (score 2):

One liner

```
{k: list(i for (i, _) in v) for k, v in itertools.groupby(zip(A, sessionid), operator.itemgetter(1))}
```

Without nested loop

```
{k: list(map(operator.itemgetter(0), v)) for k, v in itertools.groupby(zip(A, sessionid), operator.itemgetter(1))}
```

Comment: You still need to import itertools :)

Comment: One line but a nested loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
import pandas as pd

A = ['T', 'D', 'Q', 'D', 'D']
sessionid = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2]

pd.DataFrame({'A':A, 'id':sessionid}).groupby('id')['A'].apply(list).to_dict()

#Out[10]: {1: ['T', 'D', 'Q'], 2: ['D', 'D']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also convert them into numpy arrays, and use the indices of the session ids you need with `np.where`

```
import numpy as np

A = np.asarray(['T', 'D', 'Q', 'D', 'D'])
sessionid = np.asarray([1, 1, 1, 2, 2])

Ind_1 = np.where(sessionid == 1)
Ind_2 = np.where(sessionid == 2)

print A[Ind_1]
```

should return  `['T' 'D' 'Q']`

you could of course turn this into a function which takes N, the desired session and returns your A values.

Hope this helps!