# Python calculations in two groups

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have the following two lists:

```
          level = ["a","b","a","c"]
          Number = [1,2,1,2]
```

And i am just wondering if I could use Python calculate the sum Number for each element in list level. So the output would be two new lists x and y:

```
          x = ["a", "b","c"]
          y = [2,2,2]  (e.g: the total Number for "a" is 1+1=2, etc)
```

Comment: You can use Python to do this, what have you tried?

Comment: Should your `y` in this case be `[2, 1, 1]` ?

Comment: please edit your question according to @SnehalShekatkar so that you won't confuse members who want to help you

Comment: @SnehalShekatkar  thx for asking! actually it is [2,2,2] as they are the sum of number in the list frequency, it is a little bit confusing as they are not the actual "frequency" for each element in the list level, i am trying to group by numbers in list frequency.

Comment: @SnehalShekatkar I would think it's `[2, 1, 2]` because even though `c` appears once, it has a single value of `2` for frequency. Note this is looking a bit like homework on lists considering a very similar question was asked [earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36719385/python-group-two-lists) again with no demonstrated code

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ thx for the heads up! i just changed it to Number instead of "Frequency", i guess this is less confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) if you don't care about the order in `x`, although I'm sure there's a more practical way to do this

```
from collections import defaultdict
defdic = defaultdict(int)
for letter, frequency in zip(level, frequency):
    defdic[letter] += frequency

x,y = list(defdic.keys()), list(defdic.values())

# or better yet as proposed by Bharel
x, y = zip(*defdic.items())
```

**Output**:

```
>>> x 
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> y 
[2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: thx! i dont care about the orders of X, actually i was testing ur code and x is in alphabetic orders automatically (i dont know why, ) but thx for the heads up!

Comment: `x` _won't_ be in order automatically, it will change as dictionaries do not maintain order, be aware.

Answer (score 3):

One way would be using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
for k,v in zip(level, frequency):
    d[k] += v
```

Another way would be using a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
import itertools
d = Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(itertools.repeat, level, frequency)))
```

In both ways you can unpack it into 2 lists like so:

```
x, y = zip(*d.items())
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to create key mapping for them.

Below code, I create dictionary with mapping. And check, if your `level` is not exist in `dict` then sum your `frequency` with `0` else sum with last calculated `frequency`.

```
>>> level = ["a","b","a","c"]
>>> frequency = [1,2,1,2]
>>> my_dict = {}
>>> for (l, f) in zip(level, frequency):
...     my_dict[l] = my_dict.get(l, 0) + f
... 
>>> print my_dict
{'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'b': 2}
>>> print my_dict.values()
[2, 2, 2]
>>> print my_dict.keys()
['a', 'c', 'b']
```